# Error calling the overloaded istream operator in a Template Class

Tags: c++

I want to overload the ">>" operator in a template class, but when I am trying to write someting into a vector I am getting some errors.
This is a part of my Vector function:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Vector
{
public:
  T operator[](const int& i);

  template <T> friend 
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Vector &v);

  template <T> friend 
  std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Vector<T> &v);
};


template<typename T> 
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Vector<T> &v) {
  for(int i =0; i < v.getSize(); i++) {
    in >> v[i];
  }
}
```

I used this test to write into a vector:

```
int main {
     Vector<int> v1(5);
     cin >> v1;
}
```

This is the error:

```
Vector.h: In function ‘std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Vector<T>&) [with T = int, std::istream = std::basic_istream<char>]’:
testVector.cpp:9:9:   instantiated from here
Vector.h:94:3: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator>>’ in ‘in >> (& v)->Vector<T>::operator[] [with T = int]((*(const int*)(& i)))’
Vector.h:94:3: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:122:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT,
```

This is a part of my code. If I am using in a test function only something like this, it compiles:

```
Vector<int> v1.
cout << v1.getSize();
```

Update:
I've modified the >> operator overloading definition like this:

```
template<typename T> std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Vector<T> &v) {
    T tmp;
    for(int i =0; i < v.getSize(); i++) {
        in >> tmp;
        v[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

This is the definition of the operator[]:

```
template<typename T> T Vector<T>::operator[](const int& i) {
    return elements[i];
}
```

I get this error:

```
Vector.h:96:3: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

How should I overwrite the >> operator?
Thanks.

Comment: Due to 'def:' it is no c++ - Please provide things, that compile

Comment: How does this even work? How does it know which Vector template it is using?

Comment: I put a part of my code...def is an indication to show that this is the definition of >>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines:

```
template <T> friend std::ostream& ...
template <T> friend std::istream& ...
```

The template argument should be a type. As you've written it, it takes an *object* of said type.

```
template<typename U> friend std::ostream& ...
template<typename U> friend std::istream& ...
```

And you didn't specify a template argument here:

```
Vector v1(5);
      ^
```

Comment: I updated my post. I forgot to specify the template argument in my post. In my code I put it.

Comment: @georgiana_e Did my answer help? Did it solve the problem here? If so, could you please accept it by clicking the checkmark? It helps a lot! :)

Comment: Still does't work. I've put an update in my post with the error I am getting now.

Comment: @georgiana_e You're trying to assign a value to the object returned by `operator[]`, but the object returned is a temporary whose value you cannot change. You need to return a `T&` from your `operator[]`.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with stream overloading:

1. You have two constructors with the same argument `int`. The names of the constructor doesn't matter main thing is the type. So two `Vector<T>(int)` will give you error overloading error.
2. You do not have an overloaded subscript operator (`operator[]`), set it up to fix the main problem
3. as 0x499602D2 mentioned, change the friend classes to the correct form because you will get error "accessing private member variable of class Vector" if you tried to use private members. In your scenario, you are accessing public members, so you might not even need friending the stream overloading. Read about friend [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/). So, ask yourself a question? "Will the stream operator function access the private member of class Vector?" If yes, use friend; otherwise remove it from your class declaration.
4. Remove the `def` from the source code. We understand that its coming from a source file.
5. The test program doesn't work because you haven't specified which template parameter you are using.

EDIT: added link for (3) to read about friendship

Comment: I only put a part of my code, I overload the [] operator, and I put by mistake in the post two constructors. The problem is that if I remove the "cin >> v1" it compiles if I call other method from the Vector class, but if I let the "cin >> v1" line I am getting that compile error. I put def in my post only to suggest that this is the definition of the overloading operator >>.